# How to get the current selected account in Metamask?

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix

How to get the **current selected** account in Metamask?

I've seen things like this as [the answer to this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79042/how-can-i-get-the-current-user-account-selected-in-metamask-with-web3-js)..

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
const account = accounts[0];
```

But doesn't this just select the first account? Not the current selected account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

metamask ethereum provider now recommends to use the following method for getting the current enabled account:

`var accountsOnEnable = await ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});`

Variable `ethereum` is now existing since the MetaMask version update. Method `await web3.eth.getAccounts()` is also working to get the current enabled account, but since the metamask provider recommends to use the other way, I would go with the example above.

Comment: var accountsOnEnable = await ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'}); this is giving the list of accounts there in the metamask web3.eth.getAccounts() not working it says there is no function like that

Comment: I have also gone through the files of web3.js there is no function getAccounts()